# react-redux useSelector() hook not working

Tags: react-native, redux-saga

I am new to React Native Programming. So, please tell me in detail. thank you.

[calling use Selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qgbu.png)

I am calling use Selector inside my functional component like this:

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
const AddAddressScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const data = useSelector(state => state);
    console.log(data + "happy Coding");

  return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
<View>
);
}

export default AddAddressScreen;
```

My reducer looks like this

```
 case types.API_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            if (action.result.result.mobile_verified === false) {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    onLoad: false,
                    result: action.result,
                    status: action.status,
                    error: null,
                    navigation: action.navigation.navigate("VerifyMNO")
                };
            } else {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    onLoad: false,
                    result: action.result,
                    status: action.status,
                    error: null,
                    navigation: action.navigation.navigate("AddAddress")
                };
            }
```

here my mobile number is verified so I move to the address screen.
where I use Use Selector which gives me an error. while I remove above two lines my code runs successfully.

My saga looks like this

```
export function* watchLoginUserInfo() {
    yield takeLatest(types.LOGIN_USER, loginApiSaga) 
}
```

My root saga

```
import { all, fork } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { watchLoginUserInfo,  } from './authenticationSagas';
function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        watchLoginUserInfo(),
    ])
}
export default rootSaga;
```

My Store looks like this

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../redux/reducers/root-reducer.js'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import rootSaga from '../redux/sagas/rootSaga';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);


export {store};
```

when ever I use use Selector hook in my code it gives me the following error.
[error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlcT4.png)
[error 2, 3, 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFHdH.png)

Comment: Welcome! Please [do not post code, errors and logs as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), but copy the relevant parts into the question instead, refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: we need more code than this 2 lines to understand what's wrong

Comment: hi @l4rnaud I provide some more Information about my question.

Comment: hi @zsltg I provide some more Information about my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `select` effect from `redux-saga` inside of a reducer: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#selectselector-args

For example `const selectedState = yield select(state => state);`.

The `useSelector` hook is for use inside of a function component.

EDIT: since the above doesn't seem to be the issue, I think the issue is that you're calling navigation functions from within your reducer. Reducer code can have no side effects, so you can't call `navigation.navigate(...)` from within the reducer. This will need to happen in the saga code instead. It might be able to be done in the `loginApiSaga` or in a dedicated saga that is triggered by `API_LOGIN_SUCCESS`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But I am using use Selector Hook from inside my functional component. Please look at my question again I provided some more information now.